# Having trouble with rails current_page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Trying to use `current_page?` but keep gettting a no route error.

Here's the route I'm trying to match:

```
  match 'firefly/signin', :to => 'Firefly::Sessions#create', :as => :firefly_signin
```

Here's what I'm using in the view:

```
  <% unless current_page?(:controller => 'session') %>
```

But it doesn't like that. Adding `:action => 'new'` doesn't work either.

Comment: What's error, provide it's description?

Comment: I said it's a no route error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% unless current_page?(firefly_signin_url) %>
```